# Extract data from json file throush "powershell" command

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to get data from my `json` file but my code is still not working. Do you have any suggestion ?

JSON file :

```
  "nodes": [

    {

      "id": "elfe",

      "apps": [

        {

          "id": "man1",

          "age" = "5"

          "power" ="strenght"

        },

        {

          "id": "man2",

          "age" = "10"

          "power" ="strenght"

        }],

      "id": "monster",


      "apps": [

        {

          "id": "man3",

          "age" = "5"

          "power" ="strenght"

        },

        {

          "id": "man4",

          "age" = "10"

          "power" ="strenght"

        }],
```

And there, my code in PowerShell. I just want to get `man1`, `man2`, `man3`, `man4` values in my file for each `id` elfe and monster like that :

```
man1
man2
```

in one file and in the other file:

```
man3
man4
```

My batch script :

```
Powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Content .\config.json |ConvertFrom-Json).Nodes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id | Where-Object id -eq elfe" >> file.txt
```

EDIT : I can't modify my JSON file...

Comment: when i try to use your sample with `ConvertFrom-JSON`, i get the following error = `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:  [`. have you tested the file to see if it is actually valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is not valid, below is corrected version with data extraction:

```
$json = @" 
{
 "nodes":[

    {

      "id":"elfe",

      "apps":[

        {

          "id":"man1",

          "age":5,

          "power":"strenght"

        },

        {

          "id":"man2",

          "age":10,

          "power":"strenght"

        }]},

     { "id":"monster",


      "apps":[

        {

          "id":"man3",

          "age" :"5",

          "power":"strenght"

        },

        {

          "id":"man4",

          "age":"10",

          "power":"strenght"

        }]}
    ]}
"@

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json 

$data.nodes | where {$_.id -eq "elfe"} | foreach {$_.apps.id >> "elfe.txt"}
```

But probably you just had troubles with  quoting that command. Below is a working version. I replaced >> with tee - it will overwrite output file and also prints results on the screen.

```
powershell -nop  -c "(cat test.json | ConvertFrom-Json).nodes | where {$_.id -eq 'elfe'} | foreach {$_.apps.id} | tee out.txt"
```

Comment: ok thans for your answer ! is it possible to have the same result with using : Powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Content .\config.json | where {$_.id -eq "elfe"} | foreach {$_apps.id} >> "elfe.txt"  ?